# Is there a way of picking a life insurance agent who is a fiduciary?

Tags: united-states, life-insurance, whole-life, universal-life

We got a company with a CPA and financial adviser come to present at work and one mentioned life insurance. Is there a way to pick figure out who is the best agent to work with when it comes to picking life insurance? I have seen a number of agents who do it part-time and I don't think they understand the best way of seeing how well the insurance would fit into someone's plan.

Are there any agents that are fiduciary agents? And not just selling for the commission?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any agents that are fiduciary agents?

The fee only fiduciary planner you use will help you determine how much insurance and what kinds you need. They don't care which high rated company you pick, but they will help you calculate the amount you need. They will also be able to explain the different types.

> Is there a way to pick figure out who is the best agent to work with
> when it comes to picking life insurance?

The best is either the cheapest policy that meets you needs from a high rated company, or one that is highly rated, local, and offer a wide variety of policies besides life insurance. They offer home and auto so that you can get a multi-line discount.